# Launch on page load instead of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following displays a box on the page when it's clicked.

```
<div class="launcher-var" data-var="box4"><a href="javascript:void(0)">x</a></div>
```

how can I display this box on page load with javascript or jQuery if the URL is www.domain.com/id=box4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript :

```
var button = document.querySelector('.launcher-var a'),
    yourLink = 'www.domain.com/id=box4?';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 if(window.location.href == yourLink ){
  button.click();
 }
});
```

Answer after the comment: 
**It's not the URL it if the URL has id=box4 on page load – John Higgins 6 mins ago**

**The solution :**

```
var button = document.querySelector('.launcher-var a');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("id=box4") > -1 ){
  button.click();
 }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.location.href == "www.domain.com/id=box4"){ 
 //open box here
 }
)};
```

Comment: The button isn't clicked. It's if the URL has id=box4 I want it to display box4

Answer (score -1):

I got it working using the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('?id=') > 0){ 
       $(".launcher-var").click();
    }
});
```